# JSENCODE doesnt work for Set<String> in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I was working on a scenario where I had to apply JSENCODE for the Set iterated in apex:pageBlockTable. However it gives me error as incorrect argument for JSENCODE error. Hence i had to add the set into a string and then use the JSENCODE function which worked . I wish to know why it doesnt work with SET but works with List . What corrections should i make to get the below code working

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!resultsLst}" var="a" id="tblResults">                        
  <apex:column >
   <apex:facet name="header">
   <apex:outputPanel >Team Name</apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:facet>
  <a href="#" onclick = "setValuesFunction('{!JSENCODE(a)}');"> {!a} </a>  **HERE THE JSENCODE FUNCTION GIVES ERROR AS INCORRECT ARGUMENT**                                             
  </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**In controller**

```
    public with sharing class XYZ{

    public  static Set<String> results{get;set;} 

    public XYZ() 
    {

    results = new Set<String>();
    }




 public static void runSearch() 
    {

        if(searchString != '' && searchString != null )
        {
            results = performSearch(searchString);

        }
    } 


     public static Set<String> performSearch(String searchString1) {

            Set<String> uniqueTeamNameSet = new Set<String>();
          // do something 

            return uniqueTeamNameSet; 
    }

}
```

PS:

> WHEN PAGEBLOCK IS ITERATED OVER LIST I AM ABLE TO USE JSENCODE
>   BT NOT WITH SET

Comment: I can suggest cast it to set, and then back to list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When set comes to page it's iterated variable will be treated as object.
JSENCODE Accepts only string parameter that is why it will not allow to save the code.
WorkAround - First convert the value to string on page then use JSENCODE 
eg -

```
//I have the set here named Temp
<apex:repeat value="{!temp}" var="setValue">
    //Adding a space just before the iterated value and assigning to new variable. which now is converted to string
    <apex:variable value=" {!setValue}" var="TemporaryVariable"/>
    Printing out temporary variable
    {!JSENCODE(TemporaryVariable)}
</apex:repeat>
```